# Wald Chi-square with survey weights in Python

Tags: python, sas, survey-weights, wald-test

I am trying to perform a Wald (Chi-square) test in Python using survey data with sample weights. I have looked in Scikit learn and statsmodels, but neither seem to support this test where the sample weights are taken into consideration.

I know how to do this in SAS:

```
proc surveyfreq data = my_data varmethod = jackknife;
weight sample_weight;
repweights repweight1-repweight50 / df = 49 jkceofs = 0.98;
tables var1*var2 / row col wchisq;
run;
```

I also know of the survey package in R. However, my use case requires a Python solution.

Is there equivalent functionality in the aforementioned libraries or some other library that I did not mention?

Comment: I've never found one. You can use the survey package in R though.